# How to iterate through an object and join one of it's attributes in a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I feel like there's a way to do the following code in ruby using just one line. Any takers?

```
arr = []
sample_object.all.each { |o| arr << o.id }
arr.join(', ')
```

This would return a string of id's for that object join by a ',' like:

```
"1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9"
```

Comment: `simple_object.all.map(&:id).join(', ')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right there is a simpler way; Use `map` or `collect`. Example using `collect`:

```
sample_object.all.collect(&:id).join(', ');
```

Reference: [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html)

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between map and collect?

Comment: @Breno, no difference, use either.  Please see referenced documentation.

Answer (score 2):

First there's no need to build `arr`, we could just write

`sample_object.all.map { |o| o.id }.join(', ')`

[`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-map) allows us to covert an array of `sample_object`s to their `id`s returned by the block.

We can simplify that further using [`to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc):

`sample_object.all.map(&:id).join(', ')`

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised to see no mention of `pluck`, which if you only want the id's of the objects would be an obvious contender since it's [faster and less resource intensive](http://rubyinrails.com/2014/06/05/rails-pluck-vs-select-map-collect/) than mapping/collecting across fully initialised objects.

```
sample_object.all.pluck(:id).join(', ')
```